# Prove or disprove that the successive maxima of sums of i.i.d. increments are a Markov process

Tags: markov-process

> Let $\{\xi_n\}$  be independent, identically distributed, random variables.
> Define    $S_k =  \sum\limits_{i=0}^k \xi_i $  and $\eta_k = \max(S_0, ..., S_k)$.
> How to prove or disprove that $\{ \eta_k\}$ is a Markov process?

I have a feeling that $\{ \eta_k\}$ is not a Markov process, but don't know how to rigorously prove it.

#### My attempt

I think it is sufficient to show that assuming $\xi \sim U_{[-1/2 ; 1/2]}$ the following is true:
$$ P\left(\eta_3 > \frac{1}{2}  ~~\Big|~~ \eta_2 = \frac{1}{2} , \eta_1 = \frac{1}{2} \right)\neq  P\left(\eta_3 > \frac{1}{2}  ~~\Big|~~ \eta_2 = \frac{1}{2} \right) $$

The left part of the above is
$$  P\left(\eta_3 > \frac{1}{2}  ~~\Big|~~ \eta_2 = \frac{1}{2} , \eta_1 = \frac{1}{2} \right) =  P\left(\xi_3 > -\xi_2 ~\Big|~ \xi_1  = \frac{1}{2}, \xi_2 < 0\right) $$
The right part is
$$ P\left(\eta_3 > \frac{1}{2}  ~~\Big|~~ \eta_2 = \frac{1}{2} \right)  = P\left(\xi_3 > -\xi_2 ~\Big|~ \xi_1  = \frac{1}{2}, \xi_2 < 0\right) + P\left(\xi_3 > 0 ~\Big|~ \xi_1 + \xi_2  = \frac{1}{2}, \xi_1 < \frac{1}{2} \right)  $$
And the problem is to prove that the last term $P\left(\xi_3 > 0 ~\Big|~ \xi_1 + \xi_2  = \frac{1}{2}, \xi_1 < \frac{1}{2} \right)  $  is non zero

And it really seems, that it is non zero, because $\{\xi_3 > 0\}$ and $ \{\xi_1 + \xi_2  = \frac{1}{2}\}$ are independent.

Am i right ?

Comment: "I have a feeling that it is not Markov process, but don't know how to rigorously prove it." A common approach then is to find a counterexample. Did you do anything in this direction?

Comment: If I could find one, i wouldn't post such a question here.

Comment: I did not say "find", I said "do anything in this direction". Do you understand the difference?

Comment: I dont think my attempt is right, but i posted it, as you suggested

Comment: The decomposition of the RHS is not correct. You write $P(A\mid B\cup C)$ with $B\cap C=\varnothing$ as $P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid C)$ while $$P(A\mid B\cup C)=\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)}{P(B)+P(C)}=\frac{P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid C)P(C)}{P(B)+P(C)}.$$ Correcting this step while keeping the same approach should lead you to a full solution. (Note that increments uniform on an interval may not have been the simplest choice and that $\pm1$ increments often work well in these situations.)

Comment: Am i right that assuming
$$ P(A\mid B\cup C)=\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)}{P(B)+P(C)}=\frac{P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid C)P(C)}{P(B)+P(C)} $$
the probability of $B$ is equal to 
$$P(B) = P(\{ \xi_1 = 1/2, \xi_2 < 0 \}) = 0 $$
so that  $$ P(A|B+C) = P(A|C)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ p(x) =  \mathbb{I}(x \in [-1/2;~ 1/2]) $, or equivalently $ \xi \sim U_{\left[-\frac{1}{2}; ~\frac{1}{2}\right]} $.

Consider probabilities: 
    \begin{equation}
 \begin{gathered}
 P\left( \eta_3 > 0  ~\Big|~  \eta_1 = \dfrac{1}{2},  \eta_2 = \dfrac{1}{2} \right) 
 =  P\left( \xi_3 > -\xi_2  ~\Big|~  \xi_1 = \dfrac{1}{2},~  \xi_2 < 0 \right) = \\
 = \int_{-1/2}^{0} \int_{-x_2}^{1/2} dx_3 dx_2 = \dfrac{1}{8}
 \end{gathered}
 \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
 \begin{gathered}
 P\left( \eta_3 > 0  ~\Big|~ \eta_2 = \dfrac{1}{2} \right) 
 =  P\left( \eta_3 > 0  ~\Big|~  \underbrace{\left\{ \xi_1 = \dfrac{1}{2},~  \xi_2 < 0 \right\}}_{B}  \cup \underbrace{\left\{ \xi_1  + \xi_2 = \dfrac{1}{2} \right\}}_{C}  \right)
 \end{gathered} 
 \end{equation}
Note that $ P(B \cap C) = 0 $, so
    \begin{equation}
 \begin{gathered}
 P( \eta_3 > 0  ~|~ B \cup C )  
 =  \dfrac{P(\eta_3 > 0 ~|~ B) P(B) + P(\eta_3 > 0 ~|~ C) P(C)}{P(B) + P(C)} = \\
 = P(\eta_3 > 0 ~|~ C) = P\left(\xi_3 > 0 ~\big|~ \left\{ \xi_1  + \xi_2 = \frac{1}{2} \right\} \right)
 = \dfrac{1}{2}
 \end{gathered}
 \end{equation}
    So we have proved, that Markov property is not fulfilled for such a sequence.
    \begin{equation}
  P\left( \eta_3 > 0  ~\Big|~  \eta_1 = \dfrac{1}{2},  \eta_2 = \dfrac{1}{2} \right)  \neq P\left( \eta_3 > 0  ~\Big|~   \eta_2 = \dfrac{1}{2} \right)  
 \end{equation}